Extremely slow linq query after EF Core 8 upgrade
I've got the following linq query:
return _db.LocationPolygons
    .Include(x => x.LocationPoints.OrderBy(y => y.SortOrder))
    .Where(x => x.LocationId == locationId && x.DeletedDateTime == null)
    .ToList();

It used to run extremely fast under EF Core 6.0 / .NET 6.
I've just migrated to .NET 8 and EF Core 8 and now it takes 17 seconds to execute.
But the underlying SQL being generated takes < 1 second directly in SSMS.
This is the underlying SQL being produced:
DECLARE @__locationId_0 int = 11967;

SELECT [l].[LocationPolygonId], [l].[CentroidLat], [l].[CentroidLong], [l]. 
    [DeletedDateTime], [l].[Description], [l].[Editable], [l].[LocationId], [l0]. 
    [LocationPointId], [l0].[Latitude], [l0].[LocationPolygonId], [l0].[Longitude], [l0]. 
    [SortOrder]
FROM [LocationPolygon] AS [l]
LEFT JOIN [LocationPoint] AS [l0] ON [l].[LocationPolygonId] = [l0].[LocationPolygonId]
WHERE [l].[LocationId] = @__locationId_0 AND [l].[DeletedDateTime] IS NULL
ORDER BY [l].[LocationPolygonId], [l0].[SortOrder]


I have int primary keys on both tables
I have an index on (LocationPoint) LocationPolygonId and SortOrder
I have an index on (LocationPolygon) LocationId and DeletedDateTime
I have the correct foreign key/constraint between LocationPoint.LocationPolygonId and LocationPolygon.

In terms of results, there is one LocationPolygon being returned and 44,000 LocationPoints which are related child entities that sit inside the LocationPolygon record.
Why would it take 17 seconds for EF Core to execute this?
17 seconds feels like it's doing some kind of N+1 separate call for every single one of the 44,000 child rows or something?
I've also tried .AsSplitQuery() and it had a negligible effect.
A further update:
I re-wrote the query to populate the child records manually myself directly into the destination DTO objects, rather than relying on EF Core to eager load the child entities and the query executes in < 1 second lightning fast. So the 44,000 rows and the network are definitely not the problem.
var results = from polygons in _db.LocationPolygons
                      where polygons.LocationId == locationId &&
                      polygons.DeletedDateTime == null
                      select new LocationPolygonDto
                      {
                          LocationPolygonId = polygons.LocationPolygonId,
                          CentroidLat = polygons.CentroidLat,
                          CentroidLong = polygons.CentroidLong,
                          Description = polygons.Description,
                          LocationId = locationId,
                          Editable = polygons.Editable,
                          LocationPoints = _db.LocationPoints.Where(x => x.LocationPolygonId ==  polygons.LocationPolygonId).Select(x => new PointDto { Latitude = x.Latitude, Longitude = x.Longitude }).ToList()
                      };

        return results.ToList();


Could you check how long it takes to execute just var xx = _db.Model;? It can be slow EF Core warmup.

Your claim is a little vague, What is the generated t-sql with EF 6? What is the execution time with .NET 6?  This query is running on a server or locally? because 44000 records is a big result and can be a network issue. Do you use transactions before calling this query?

Another issue which comes to my mind is that you have Parameter Snifing. Try this extension to ensure that this is not an issue. Or just put constant in LINQ query instead of variable.

Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv - it's instant (super fast) and I am already running a lot of other queries successfully before this offending query runs.

Hi @sa-es-ir - I am unable to roll back to EF 6, but I know that all my users were completely happy and literally the day I deployed EF Core 8 we received lots of complaints about slow page loads. The other reason I believe it's NOT a network issue is that when I execute the query in SSMS, I receive the full 44,000 results in under 1 second. They are very lightweight small rows with not much data, basically coordinate pairs with a couple of other very small fields and the data gets to the SSMS client instantly and SSMS has fully finished loading.

Hi guys, I've just posted an update. I re-wrote the query to populate the child entries manually into the destination dto objects and it runs lightning fast. Why is EF Core blowing the original query out to 17 seconds when return the same data with a query that is very efficient in direct SQL?

Try AsNoTracking.

Something either seems suspect with the relationship between the location and location points, or potentially there is an issue with EF resolving from the tracking cache. If you execute the SQL EF generates, does it take longer to run than expected, or is it fast to return the 44k results?
The first thing to eliminate would be the tracking cache, try the original query with .AsNoTracking() to prevent EF from inspecting or adding the loaded items into the tracking cache. If the performance improves then you likely have an aged DbContext instance in play getting bogged down with tracked entities. Heavy reads like this where you are pulling tens of thousands of entities at a time should ideally be non-tracking queries in practice, or better, projections.
The next point would be that when reading data, I always recommend using projections over entities, though as your example shows these look to be fairly lightweight so reading the entities shouldn't explain the duration issues if the performance loss is measured in the ToList() operation and not afterwards, such as when serializing a response etc. where lazy load calls might creep in. I suspect since you were capturing the SQL generated you would have easily spotted lazy load calls. From the data the only suspect there would have possibly been a LocationPoint.Location and drilling down from there if LocationPoint had a navigation property.
There is one notable difference between your first example and your adjusted projection in that the first example is ordering the Location Points while the second projection does not. That could play into indexing performance.
An adjustment to your current projection to use the navigation properties would be:
var results = _db.LocationPolygons
    .Where(p => p.LocationId == locationId 
        && p.DeletedDateTime == null)
    .Select(p => new LocationPolygonDto
    {
        LocationPolygonId = p.LocationPolygonId,
        CentroidLat = p.CentroidLat,
        CentroidLong = p.CentroidLong,
        Description = p.Description,
        LocationId = locationId,
        Editable = p.Editable,
        LocationPoints = p.LocationPoints
            .OrderBy(lp => lp.SortOrder)
            .Select(lp => new PointDto { Latitude = lp.Latitude, Longitude = lp.Longitude })
            .ToList()
    };
return results.ToList();

... which you could try with, and without the order by Sort Order. If this is still suspiciously slower than your existing projection going back to the DbContext for the Location Points then there may be some form of weird boxing or such happening in EF which might warrant checking the entity declarations for any oddness, whether null-able references or casting.
Edit: It could be coming down to an odd execution plan selection not picking up on the indexing properly. You could check this by injecting an OPTION(RECOMPILE) into the resulting execution or as a one off have the server recompile the execution plans with EXEC sp_updatestats then test the queries again.
